# Robert Altman, how to capture sound like in his movies?

Tags: recording, field-recording, recommendations, director, strategy

I'm sound designing a movie and in conversations with the director, Robert Altman emerged. I know that Altman was a director that was revolutionary in terms of sound. He was one of the first moviemakers that used many channels for a movie and the dialog of his movies have a huge refinement for improvisation since he had so many channels that he could mix it in many ways.

But do you know some methods to capture this kind of scene with good quality? Do you know the method that he used either? And if he used lavalier too? because I haven't realy been happy with lavalier sound, since they arent really good with high and low tones.

Comment: Multi-tracking existed quite apart from Robert Altman's use of the technique. Now, Mr. Altman may be notable for placing an emphasis on capturing good audio during principal shooting, and good for him. We don't know what "this kind of scene" you are asking about?  Lav mics are quire capable of frequency response well beyond what you can hear, so "aren't relly good with high and low tones" is not an accurate summary.

Comment: Remember further that you aren't necessarily hearing in the finished sound track mix what happened in front of the camera.  See also this discussion: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51154/why-motorbike-sounds-are-never-real/51193#51193